# How to get all points in table that are separated by 10 km

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a PostGIS table that stores the locations a device has passed through in the following way:

| ts | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/12/23 10:04 | -3.2654 | -79.9234 |
| 2022/12/23 10:14 | -3.2654 | -79.9234 |
| 2022/12/23 10:24 | -2.95592 | -79.6833 |

As the device is transmitting every 10 minutes, there are a lot of duplicated locations and I want to filter the positions of the device to get the points that are separated at least by 10km of any other point the device has passed through.

I tried this SQL, and it filters the duplicates that are the exact same point, but I want to add the distance check to the other points of the table.

```
SELECT  MIN(ts) AS arrivalTime, MAX(ts) AS departureTime,  "lat", "lon" FROM "logsData" 
  WHERE "lat" IS NOT NULL  
  GROUP BY lat, lon
  ORDER BY MAX(ts);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do a self-join on logsData table and generate a column to store the distance between the two points.

Comment: What do you want to do if A is 8 km from B and B is 8 km from C, and A and C are more than 10 km from each other?  Does it matter whether you keep A and C, or keep just B?  Does it matter what the timestamps on each are?

Comment: `ST_SnapToGrid()` to simplify everything down to points on a coarser lattice or use one of the clustering functions to group them. In both cases pick one from each "deduplicated" group using a `distinct on`, discarding the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I found this function ST_ClusterDBSCAN(), that creates clusters of points. Do you think I can use that to create clusters separated by 10km and then use the clusters location?

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a larger data sample and the exact expected results? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Requirements**

`logsData`  (`ts`, `lat`, `lon`) can be expressed as `gg1`, `gg2`, `gg3`.....`ggN`. To report those data points that are 10km apart requires calculating distance as below:

1. distance(`gg1`, `gg2`) >= 10km, report `gg1`, `gg2`
2. if not, calculate (gg1, ggX) until the distance >= 10km, then report `ggX`
3. now use `ggX` as origin and find next `ggY` so that distance(`ggX`, `ggY`) >= 10km
4. Repeat until all required data points are reported.

Before some SQL gurus come out an answer, here's a workaround.

**Workaround**

1. Calculate the distance between adjacent data points (in terms of 10-minute interval)
2. Calculate cumulative distance of each data point
3. Divide all data points into 10km segments: 0-10km, 10-20km, 20-30km....
4. Pick the first data point in each segment.

```sql
with cte_log_dist as (
select ts,
       lat,
       lon,       
       st_point(lon, lat) as gg,
       lag(st_point(lon, lat),1) over (order by ts) as prev_gg,
       coalesce(st_distance(lag(st_point(lon, lat),1) over (order by ts), st_point(lon, lat)),0) as distance
  from logsdata),
cte_log_seg as (
select ts,
       lat,
       lon,
       prev_gg,
       gg,
       distance,
       sum(distance) over (order by ts)                 as total_distance,
       floor(sum(distance) over (order by ts) / 10000)  as ten_km_segment 
  from cte_log_dist),
cte_log_seg_rank as (
select ts, 
       lat, 
       lon, 
       prev_gg, 
       gg, 
       distance, 
       total_distance, 
       ten_m_segment,
       row_number() over (partition by ten_km_segment) as rn
  from cte_log_seg)
select *
  from cte_log_seg_rank
 where rn = 1;
```

The output is similar to this (Note the following test data are based on 10m segment for demonstration purpose)

```
ts                     |lat |lon |prev_gg                                      |gg                                           |distance           |total_distance    |ten_m_segment|rn|
-----------------------+----+----+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------+--+
2022-01-01 00:00:00.000| 0.0|0.63|                                             |POINT (0.6299999952316284 0)                 |                0.0|               0.0|          0.0| 1|
2022-01-01 00:50:00.000|0.01|3.03|POINT (0.2899999916553497 0.0099999997764826)|POINT (3.0299999713897705 0.0099999997764826)| 2.7399999797344208|12.300009636083564|          1.0| 1|
2022-01-01 02:00:00.000|0.02| 1.6|POINT (9.289999961853027 0.0099999997764826) |POINT (1.600000023841858 0.0199999995529652) | 7.6900064399587675| 26.25001606650559|          2.0| 1|
2022-01-01 02:10:00.000|0.02|5.79|POINT (1.600000023841858 0.0199999995529652) |POINT (5.789999961853027 0.0199999995529652) |  4.189999938011169| 30.44001600451676|          3.0| 1|
2022-01-01 03:00:00.000|0.03|0.57|POINT (9.539999961853027 0.0199999995529652) |POINT (0.5699999928474426 0.0299999993294477)|  8.970005543139631|  43.1600215476564|          4.0| 1|
2022-01-01 05:10:00.000|0.03|7.87|POINT (7.090000152587891 0.0299999993294477) |POINT (7.869999885559082 0.0299999993294477) | 0.7799997329711914| 50.46002144036804|          5.0| 1|
2022-01-01 05:50:00.000|0.04|8.95|POINT (6.559999942779541 0.0399999991059303) |POINT (8.949999809265137 0.0399999991059303) | 2.3899998664855957| 60.28003353049773|          6.0| 1|
2022-01-01 06:20:00.000|0.05|1.12|POINT (0.5299999713897705 0.0500000007450581)|POINT (1.1200000047683716 0.0500000007450581)| 0.5900000333786011| 70.39003935735751|          7.0| 1|
2022-01-01 09:00:00.000|0.06|0.02|POINT (9.5600004196167 0.0500000007450581)   |POINT (0.0199999995529652 0.0599999986588955)|  9.540005661150024| 88.37004543335586|          8.0| 1|
2022-01-01 09:20:00.000|0.06|1.66|POINT (1.2599999904632568 0.0599999986588955)|POINT (1.659999966621399 0.0599999986588955) | 0.3999999761581421| 90.01004540042429|          9.0| 1|
2022-01-01 11:10:00.000|0.07|0.33|POINT (9.359999656677246 0.0599999986588955) |POINT (0.3300000131130219 0.0700000002980232)|  9.030005180663121|106.74005027114326|         10.0| 1|
```

Answer (score -1):

Run a self-join on the logsData so that there is a pairwise comparison of the locations, and then add a column to store the calculated distances. You may want to eliminate the duplicate locations before the self-join.

```
WITH
  logsdata_merge (ts_a, lat_a, lon_a, ts_b, lat_b, lon_b)
  AS
  (
    SELECT A.ts AS ts_a, A.lat AS lat_a, A.lon AS lon_a, 
           B.ts AS ts_b, B.lat AS lat_b, B.lon AS lon_b
    FROM logsData A, logsData B
  )
```

If unable to add a column to a CTE, create a new table instead of using a CTE. And then add the column for the distance values:

```
ALTER TABLE logsdata_merge ADD distance AS (...);

SELECT FROM logsdata_merge WHERE distance >= 10KM
```